# VBA Sorting CSV files by column, Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I'm trying to Sort a CSV-File by columns with the following code:

```
Sub SortCSVFile(file, sort_column)

  Set XLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  XLApp.Workbooks.Open (file)

  XLApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
  Set SortCol = XLApp.Range(sort_column)
  XLApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add (SortCol)
  Set Cell = XLApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", XLApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), , , , 2)
  Set mYRange = XLApp.Range("A1", XLApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Cell.Row, Cell.Column))

  XLApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SetRange (mYRange)
  XLApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.Apply

  XLApp.ActiveWorkbook.Save
  XLApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
  XLApp.Quit

End Sub
```

however, at the line `XLApp.Workbooks.Open (file)` I get **Run-time error '1004' Method 'Open' of object 'Workbooks' failed**
How do I fix this?

EDIT:
I've made an error while calling this makro from another one, using a literal file as first argument instead of a filepath.
However, now i get a different error at `Set SortCol = XLApp.Range(sort_column)`: **Run-ime error '1004' Application-defined or Object-defined**

Answer (score 0):

`Range` is a method of a `Worksheet`, which belongs to a `Workbook`.  You're trying to refer to it from the `Application` level, which is the parent to `Workbook`.

Try:

```
Dim wb as Workbook : Set wb = XLApp.Workbooks.Open(file)
dim ws as WorkSheet : Set ws = wb.Worksheets("mySheetNameHere")
```

And then you can refer to it like this

```
Set SortCol = ws.Range(sort_column)
```

Comment: I get **runtime error 9: index out of bounds** for `Set ws = wb.Worksheets(MySheet)`..

Comment: What's the value of `MySheet`?

Comment: The Value is `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name`

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` always refers to the workbook from which the code is coming, and then you are trying to use that name on the workbook you have opened.  It's possible that the name of the first sheet in your code file doesn't exist in the one you've opened.  If you just want the first sheet of the opened file, use `Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)`

Comment: Now i get an error at `XLApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSeer.Sort.Apply`: **Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or Object-defined** and something about an invalid sorting reference.

Comment: ActiveSheet is miss spelled.  You might want to try [VBSEdit](http://www.vbsedit.com/). It has intellisene for any created object:  Set XLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

> Set SortCol = XLApp.Range(sort_column)

If sort_column is a number then the Error 1004 Application Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed will be throw

This is valid

> Set SortCol = XLApp.Range("C1")

But I think this is what you want

> Set SortCol = XLApp.Cells(1, sort_column)

This is way too slow:

> Set Cell = XLApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", XLApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), , , , 2)

Your trying to find every cell on the sheet that isn't empty. XLApp.ActiveSheet.UsedRange will give you the same result.

- Use XLApp.ActiveSheet instead of XLApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

This is problematic

> XLApp.Workbooks.Open (file)

If calling a function only use () when you are looking for the function's return value.  Here you're not interested in it's value.  You just want to add the new workbook to XLApp.Workbooks collection. 
Either assign the function's return value to a variable

> Set xlWorkBook = XLApp.Workbooks.Open (file)

Or call the function without ()

> XLApp.Workbooks.Open file

```
Set XLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
XLApp.Workbooks.Open file
With XLApp.ActiveSheet
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    Set SortCol = .Cells(1, sort_column)
    .Sort.SortFields.Add SortCol
    .Sort.SetRange .UsedRange
    .Sort.Apply
End With
XLApp.ActiveWorkbook.Save
XLApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
XLApp.Quit
```

Comment: with this code i get **Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or Object-defined** and something about an invalid sorting reference at `.Sort.Apply`.. I don't understand why though